# Layout XML in third party theme

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, static-block

I am a beginner in Magento 2.

I installed a third party theme, in the home page, I founded this code on Layout Update XML field

```
<referenceContainer name="slide.showcase">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="home-slide15">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">home-slide15</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
```

I don't want this block (home-slide15) to be displayed  in the home page, so I tried to change the Block identifier "home-slide15" to my new block. and then I saved the home page. But I noticed that the code above remains as it is without any changes and the block identifier never changed. why!

Actually I am not familiar with Magento 2, I wanted to add some new block to the home page.

please help.

Comment: You can directly disable "ome-slide15" static block from admin.after disable, it will not show on frontend!

Comment: How can I do this ? From where?

Comment: from Admin, go to Content > Blocks > search "home-slide15" block and disable it.

Comment: Ok , Now I disable it. Thank you.... Now I want to show another block in home page, how can  I do this?